# How to get same JSP page after click on alert

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using alert popup to show a meesage on jsp page. So when user clicks on alert popup, I would want to stay user on the same jsp page. But I am getting an error 404:resource not found.

```
else if(ExstingUser!=null)
             {
                 out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                 out.println("alert('User Name is already exist');");
                 out.println("location='/index.jsp';");
                 out.println("</script>");
                 //response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");   
             }
```

I also tried with response.sendredirect (), But it's still not working. Could anyone help me out with my issue.

Comment: Usually it would be the name of your project (deployed war) followed by '/index.jsp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a small mistake, Just remove slash(/) from the location attibute

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
         out.println("alert('User Name is already exist');");
         out.println("location='index.jsp';");
         out.println("</script>");
```

Make the changes in your web.xml as below : You need to make correction in **url-pattern** tag.

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SaveInfo</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.simext.register.SaveInfo</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SaveInfo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

That's it.

Comment: Can you please show the code in your web.xml file ?

Comment: <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
   <description></description>
 <display-name>SaveInfo</display-name>  
 <servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>com.simext.register.SaveInfo</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
  
 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>SaveInfo</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/servlet/SaveInfo</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>

Comment: @Lina I have updated my answer with Servlet as well as Web.xml.  Please make the changes and let me know if it is working.

Comment: it gives same error -  HTTP Status 404 - /UserCreationTool/servlet/SaveInfo , before editing url-pattern tag it shows alerts and then give error after changing url-pattern it directly throws error

Comment: else if(ExstingUser!=null)
        {
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
         out.println("alert('User Name is already exist');"); 
        // out.println("location='index.jsp';");
         out.println("</script>");
         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp"); 
         rd.include(request,response);
        }            I tried this it works but my css on index,jsp is disable and it comes simple form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149102/discussion-between-sforsujit-and-lina).